# IIS7.5 Virtual Directory Wrong Physical Path

Tags: iis-7.5, failover, failovercluster, windows-cluster, virtual-directory

I have been fighting this problem for hours, and I can't make IIS (7.5 on 2008r2) do the right thing. Every time I try to go to the `photos` virtual directory, I get a 404.0 and the physical path listed is wrong and different from the physical path I setup on the virtual directory. Here is the setup:

I have a virtual directory `photos` setup under the Default Web Site.

The Default Web Site's physical path is `G:\inetpub\wwwroot` and it's only binding is *:80. The application pool for the website is setup to run as a domain user created for this purpose. That user has permissions to the mentioned G path, and the F path below.

The virtual directory has alias `photos`, physical path `F:\photos`. When I click Test Settings, it comes back successful. (The application pool user can access the path.)

When I click Browse on the photos virtual directory, I get a 404.0 - Not Found. Plus the following information.

```
Requested Url: http://localhost:80/photos
Physical Path: G:\inetpub\wwwroot\photos
```

The physical path is clearly wrong and not what I configured. What am I doing wrong?

**Log Entry**

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.5
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2015-01-29 01:44:48
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2015-01-29 01:44:48 ::1 GET /photos - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko 404 0 2 1403
```

**Page Error message**

```
Module        IIS Web Core 
Notification  MapRequestHandler 
Handler       StaticFile 
Error Code    0x80070002 
Requested URL http://localhost:80/photos
Physical Path G:\inetpub\wwwroot\photos
Logon Method  Anonymous 
Logon User    Anonymous
```

**Missing piece of this puzzle**: IIS is setup as a failover service with a shared configuration in a 2008 R2 failover cluster.

Comment: What do your logs say?

Comment: request log says status 404, subcode 0, win32 status 2

Comment: Please edit your question and include the entire log message.

Comment: Added the full IIS request log line. There's nothing in the event logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the apparent reason this was happening was the shared configuration and / or failover cluster. Even after changing the virtual directory configuration, the old configuration was cached and even restarting IIS would not cause it to be refreshed.

I was only able to get the configuration to reload by migrating the service to another node. Then the virtual directory was working properly.

Answer (score 0):

"Remove" the problem website and then add it again along with the virtual directories from IIS Manager may help. It works in my case.